# Is it best practice for a namespace to have the same name as the project in which it is found in?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, project

Say I have the following structure in my solution:

MySolution -> ProjectA -> ClassA.cs

By default, the name of the first namespace in project ProjectA is `ProjectA`.

```
namespace ProjectA
{
    public class ClassA
    { 
        // body
    }
}
```

Is it best/common practice for the name of the first namespace, within a project, to have the same name as the project in which it is found in?

Or should I change the default name of the first namespace?

Comment: I don't think it is best nor bad practice,but it seems to be the general practice and a useful one for small projects, or in practice programs (probably that's why it is the default structure when creating a library or other projects at VS2019). Also, keep in mind that the purpose of `namespace`(s) is to help you keep the code organized and avoid naming class collisions. As long as the names serve that purpose, you can name them whatever way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. The top level namespace having the same name as the project is common and perfectly fine for many projects. When working on code that uses classes from that namespace, this helps you easily identify where the source files exist in the project structure.

But if you're writing a library that you plan to publish, heed Microsoft's framework design guidelines for [Names of Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-namespaces):

> DO prefix namespace names with a company name to prevent namespaces from different companies from having the same name.

And

> DO use PascalCasing, and separate namespace components with periods (e.g., Microsoft.Office.PowerPoint).

So if your project is named `Foo`, your namespace would be `MyCompany.Foo`.

Comment: But technically if my project is named "Foo" wouldn't the name of the top level namespace just be "Foo" rather than "MyCompany.Foo"?

Comment: That's fine if you're *not* planning to publish it. (Or if the project name is very unique.)

Comment: It seems that rule 1 is not really followed that strictly. However, for many open-source projects, there isn't really a company at all.

Comment: @TechInquisitor Ok. I guess what I'm asking is how would I prefix the name of the top level namespace, of a project, with the name of the company? The only reasonable approach of doing so is if my project was named "MyCompany.Foo" but in your example the project was simply named "Foo". Which is why I question how "MyCompany" became part of the name "MyCompany.Foo" of the top level namespace if the project was not named "MyCompany.Foo" Since the top level namespace gets it name (by default) from the name of the project in which is found in.

Comment: @MalcomFincher I'm suggesting that if you're concerned about disambiguating the namespace of a published project, the project should still be named `Foo`, and only the namespace should include the company or some other identifier.

Comment: @TechInquisitor But how is the company name "MyCompany" included in the name of the top level namespace if not inlcuded in the name of the project. Your example is not correct. Becuase the top level namespace gets its name from the project.

Comment: @PMF as a second opinion, do you agree with my argument? Or is Tech Inquisitor correct?

Comment: @TechInquisitor hopefully I was clear in what I was trying to explain

Comment: @MalcomFincher You can make the namespace whatever you want. You can change the default namespace for a project in the project properties.

Comment: @MalcomFincher can you give an example?  The recommendation is to use company.project as namespace. What would you do?

Comment: @PMF The Inquisitor says that if i'm wrtiiting a Library that that I plan to publish, the top level namespace should be prefixed with the name of the Company (e.g. "MyCompany"). In his example (see his answer to my post above), if the name of the project is "Foo" how is it that the name of the top level namespace is "MyCompany.Foo" if the project was not named "MyCompany.Foo". The top level namespace gets its name (by default) from the name of the project in which it is found in. See the example I gave in my post.

Comment: @PMF (in continuation to my above comment...) So basically in the Inquisitor's example I dont see how the name of the top level namespace was "MyCompany.Foo" , unless the project was named "MyCompany.Foo" but in his example even though the project was named "Foo" the name of the top level namespace is "MyCompany.Foo"??? I dont see how the "MyCompany." portion became part of the top level namespace's name... Hopefully that made more sense :) i'd really appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: @PMF I don't disagree with the recommendation. But I disagree with the" Inquisitor's example" of the recomentation. Because how is the name of the top level namespace "MyCompany.Foo" if the project was named "Foo"?

Comment: @MalcomFincher I already answered that. You can change the default namespace for a project in the project properties.

Comment: @TechInquisitor oh ok. After having taken the steps you advised I noticed that even after I made the change in the library project's "Properties" the top level namespace still retains the name it had even after I made the change. For example: Say I create a library project named "BarLibraryProject". As a result the top level namespace is called "BarLibraryProject" by defualt. But then I make the changes you advised in the project's "Properties". So now i change the "defualt namespace" from "BarLibraryProject" to "CompanyFoo.BarLibraryProject". I save the changes.

Comment: @TechInquisitor but even after i save the changes made in the project's "Properties" the top level namespace definition in the source code file still retains its original name. Being  "BarLibraryProject". So what was the point of the change of the defualt namespace. Perhaps if you can give a code example in your answer it would mean a lot me as I am still trying to figure this out.

Comment: @MalcomFincher The change should take effect on any new files. You can change old files by hand or by putting the cursor in the namespace and pressing Alt-Enter or using the refactor option in the menu.

Comment: @TechInquisitor I just now tested out what you advised above and yes you are correct the change is seen with any new source code file that I add. Thanks. Quick question though: Wouldnt it just be simpler to name the project "MyCompany.Foo" so that the top level namespace can be given that name, by default... Instead of taking that extra step in making a change in the project's "Properties"?

Comment: @TechInquisitor any thoughts on my above comment would be greatly appreciated. Hope to hear from you soon. Thanks:)

Comment: @MalcomFincher That's just a matter of personal preference. I'd rather not have to widen the project explorer to see the full names of projects in a solution.

Comment: @TechInquisitor And prefixing a namespace with the name of a company only applies to developing a Library project (Library) correct? Specifically referring to a library project that i plan to release on Nuget?

Comment: @MalcomFincher Nuget, or anywhere your library name might collide with another.